# Stdout from a C program in Spyder

Tags: python, c, ctypes, spyder

I have written C code that I am calling in Python using Ctypes. If I run the code from a simple python shell, the debug messages I have (printf commands) work just fine. I like to use Spyder as an IDE. When I run the python code that calls my C code, it runs correctly, but none of the messages from printf() commands show up in the python interpreter.

Is there a way to get the messages to show up in Spyder?

Comment: Are you using the [IPython console](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/ipythonconsole.html) or the [simple console](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/console.html)? If the simple console, is it an interpreter window, a script window, or a system command window?

Comment: I wouldn't implement a workaround that depends on a specific CRT, OS, or IDE. The library could use a debug print function set by the user. Set it to a ctypes callback. Maybe use `snprintf` in a macro to get around the lack of `va_list` support in ctypes.

Comment: I'm using the simple console with an interpreter. From what I could find, it seems Spyder redirects the stdout and stderr fro Qt signals. And the interpreter isn't a real console window. But there must be some way to use the same stream.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the warning functions to print the message.
Of course, this is just for debugging purposes.

```
char* cMsg[500];
sprintf(cMsg, "a message from C %s  %d\n", "some string", 100);    
PyErr_WarnEx(NULL, cMsg, 0);
```